# xcode shortcuts - add text/ limit text till page guide

Tags: xcode, editor, shortcut

I want to insert a piece of text using a keyboard shortcut or  single click instead of copying ans pasting the whole time. Can I do that in Xcode?

also, I have a page guide at x=80 in my xcode editor. Can I limit all my statements till that vertical line?
i.e., if I am writing a new line, it should automatically inset a new line character when that page guide is reached. Also, any old code that I wrote I might want to wrap that up within x=80.

Comment: I am also looking for the answer. Did you find the answer? If yes, please share.

Comment: I am afraid I couldn't find any such thing.